IndexedDB: Opening a new DB but Promise gets stuck
Currently, I'm designing IndexedDB functionality for my company. I have built a solid class and all of my unit tests work. However, when I'm attempting to open a new database for a client, the state of my Reducer never updates so the site hangs. I believe it is because the initDatabase method is looking for a resolution to the Promise. Here's the Reducer I've built:
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { DatabaseManager } from '../DatabaseManager';

// Async thunk to initialize the database
export const initializeDatabase = createAsyncThunk(
  'database/initialize',
  async (dbName, thunkAPI) => {
    try {
      const databaseManager = new DatabaseManager();
      await databaseManager.initDatabase(dbName);
      return databaseManager;
    } catch (error) {
      return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error.message);
    }
  }
);

const databaseSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'database',
  initialState: {
    instance: null,
    status: 'idle',
    error: null,
  },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(initializeDatabase.pending, (state) => {
        state.status = 'loading';
      })
      .addCase(initializeDatabase.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'succeeded';
        state.instance = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(initializeDatabase.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.status = 'failed';
        state.error = action.error.message;
      });
  },
});

export default databaseSlice.reducer;

Here's the initDatabase method:
async function initDatabase(dbName) {
  // Validate dbName
  if (!dbName || typeof dbName !== 'string' || !/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(dbName)) {
    throw new Error('Invalid dbName: Must be a non-empty alphanumeric string');
  }

  // Prevent reinitialization of db if already created
  if (this._db) {
    console.log(`Database ${this._db.name} is already initialized.`);
    return this._db;
  }

  // Standardize name that will populate in browser
  const request = window.indexedDB.open(dbName);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request.onsuccess = (event) => {
      this._db = event.target.result;
      resolve(this._db);
    };

    request.onerror = (event) => {
      console.error(`Failed to initialize ${dbName}: ${event.target.errorCode}`);
      reject(event.target.error);
    };
  });
}

What do I need to change to resolve the Promise and get the action.payload to the state?

You also need to listen for the blocked event when connecting. The promise will never resolve when the open request is blocked. A typical reason for being blocked is that there is a database connection doing something in another tab.

Your code doesn't appear to handle the upgradeneeded event on the open request, which will be fired before success when the database is first created or when the version is incremented.
Try adding an onupgradeneeded handler, which is necessary anyway because that's where you create object stores and indexes to actually hold data.

You can follow the official documentation to call the onupgradeneeded event:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBOpenDBRequest/upgradeneeded_event


// Open the database
const dBOpenRequest = window.indexedDB.open("toDoList", 4);

dBOpenRequest.onupgradeneeded = (event) => {
  const db = event.target.result;
  console.log(`Upgrading to version ${db.version}`);

  // Create an objectStore for this database
  const objectStore = db.createObjectStore("toDoList", {
    keyPath: "taskTitle",
  });

  // define what data items the objectStore will contain
  objectStore.createIndex("hours", "hours", { unique: false });
  objectStore.createIndex("minutes", "minutes", { unique: false });
  objectStore.createIndex("day", "day", { unique: false });
  objectStore.createIndex("month", "month", { unique: false });
  objectStore.createIndex("year", "year", { unique: false });
};



